# Looping through a list and using elements within that list

Tags: r, loops

In the code below, instead of starting with p=0.01 and then incrementing it, I'd like to be able to do something like p=(1:99)/100 and then just loop through p. For example, instead of p=0.01, let's let p=(1:99)/100. Now, I try to replace 1:99 in my for loop with p. When I run the code, however, I start having problems with coverage[i] (it returns numeric(0)). It seems like this should be fairly trivial so I'm hoping I'm just overlooking something in my code.

Also, if you see any easy boosts in efficiency please feel free to chime in! Thanks =)

```
w=seq(.01,.99,by=.01)
coverage=seq(1:99)
p=0.01

for (i in 1:99){
    count = 0
    for (j in 1:1000){
        x = rbinom(30,1,p)  
        se=sqrt(sum(x)/30*(1-sum(x)/30)/30)
        if( sum(x)/30-1.644854*se < p && p < sum(x)/30+1.644854*se )
        count = count + 1
    }
    coverage[i]=count/1000
    print(coverage[i])
    p=p+0.01 
}
```

Comment: Consider: > rbinom(1,1,2)
[1] NaN
Warning message:
In rbinom(1, 1, 2) : NAs produced

Answer (score 7):

I would work on the middle part rather than that outer loop.

```
coverage <- p <- 1:99/100
z <- qnorm(0.95)

for (i in seq(along=p) ){
  # simulate all of the binomials/30 at once
  x <- rbinom(1000, 30, p[i])/30

  # ses
  se <- sqrt(x * (1-x)/30)

  # lower and upper limits
  lo <- x - z*se
  hi <- x + z*se

  # coverage
  coverage[i] <- mean(p[i] > lo & p[i] < hi)
}
```

This is almost instantaneous for me.  The trick is to vectorize those simulations and calculations.  Increasing to 100,000 simulation replicates took just 4 seconds on my 6-year-old Mac Pro.

(You'll want to increase the replicates to see the structure in the results; `plot(p, coverage, las=1)` with 100k reps gives the following; it wouldn't be clear with just 1000 reps.)
[image: plot of coverage]

Comment: WOW. Thank you very much. I am loving the speed on this; some very slick coding there =)

Comment: However, anyone with additional input on the original question please add your comments. I believe it would still be beneficial for me to do it the clunky way

Comment: BTW - why is it better to store qnorm(0.95) in z rather than just using a number? Doesn't the program run faster if it uses a number since it doesn't have to do that calculation every time

Comment: @user722224 - I think `qnorm(0.95)` is more clear than `1.644854`, and I don't think the latter would be any faster.  Why would it be beneficial for you to do it in a clunky way?  The original question wasn't very clear.

Comment: Apologies that the question wasn't clear. I figure it would be beneficial to learn the clunky stuff just because of the whole learn to walk before you run sort of thing. I'm gonna rethink my question though so people aren't left guessing about what I mean. Thank you very much for the help though. This is what gets me excited about R and statistics!

Comment: @user722224 - Your outer loop was reasonable, so you might focus on moving the inner part a step at a time towards what I wrote.  For example, if you'd done `x <- rbinom(1, 30, p)`, you wouldn't have needed the repeated `sum(x)`.

Comment: There is dedicated `seq_along(x)` function to replace `seq(along.with=x)`.

Comment: @user722224 - note that `1.644854` isn't as accurate as `qnorm(0.95)`. I suspect you just printed it - you need to `print(qnorm(0.95), digits=17)` to get the same value: `1.6448536269514715`

Answer (score 2):

To answer the original question, setting `i in p` where `p` is 0.01, 0.02, etc, means that `coverage[i]` is trying to do `coverage[0.01]`; since `[]` requires an integer it truncates it to zero, resulting in a numeric of length zero, `numeric(0)`.

One of the other solutions is better, but for reference, to do it using your original loop, you'd probably want something like

```
p <- seq(.01, .99, by=.01)
coverage <- numeric(length(p))
N <- 1000
n <- 30
k <- qnorm(1-0.1/2)
for (i in seq_along(p)) {
    count <- 0
    for (j in 1:N) {
        x <- rbinom(n, 1, p[i]) 
        phat <- mean(x) 
        se <- sqrt(phat * (1 - phat) / n)
        if( phat-k*se < p[i] && p[i] < phat+k*se ) {
            count <- count + 1
        }
    }
    coverage[i] <- count/N
}
coverage
```

Answer (score 1):

@Karl Broman has a great solution that really shows how vectorization makes all the difference. It can still be improved slightly though (around 30%):

I prefer using `vapply` - although the speed improvement of it isn't noticeable here since the loop is only 99 times.

```
f <- function(n=1000) {
    z <- qnorm(0.95)/sqrt(30)

    vapply(1:99/100, function(p) {
      # simulate all of the binomials/30 at once
      x <- rbinom(n, 30, p)/30

      zse <- z*sqrt(x * (1-x))

      # coverage
      mean(x - zse < p & p < x + zse)
    }, numeric(1))
}

system.time( x <- f(50000) ) # 1.17 seconds
```

Here's a version of the OP's original code using `vapply` and it's about 20% faster than the original -but of course still magnitudes slower than the fully vectorized solutions...

```
g <- function(n=1000) {
    vapply(seq(.01,.99,by=.01), function(p) {
        count = 0L
        for (j in seq_len(n)) {
            x <- sum(rbinom(30,1,p))/30 

        # the constant is qnorm(0.95)/sqrt(30)
            zse <- 0.30030781175850279*sqrt(x*(1-x))
            if( x-zse < p && p < x+zse )
                count = count + 1L
        }
        count/n
    }, numeric(1))
}

system.time( x <- g(1000) ) # 1.04 seconds
```